# Symfony2: permission error with assetic and compass sprite generation

Tags: symfony, compass-sass, css-sprites, assetic

I just trying to generate a compass image sprite with assetic in symfony 2.2 project. I configured compass filter and i have some .scss files working perfect. But when I try to generate an image sprite and run ./app/console assetic:dump --watch throw an error:

```
[error] An error occurred while running:
'/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/local/bin/compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--images-dir' '/home/xuser/desarrollo/www/lab.dev/symfony/app/../web/images' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compass5atwLN' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compassiAf1jw.scss'

Error Output:
Errno::EACCES on line 43 of /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chunky_png-1.2.7/lib/chunky_png/canvas/png_encoding.rb: Permission denied - /tmp/images/sprite-s8c89b4f1b7.png
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace


Output:
...
```

I note the sprite is generated fine, but copied in /tmp/images/. 
I currently I do the same thing in a stand alone compass project and work fine, the issue is throug assetic. Could you help me?

Comment: Check the permissions on the target dir (images-dir option) and make sure the web server can write to it: /home/xuser/desarrollo/www/lab.dev/symfony/app/../web/images